# Delete in a Apex Test Class

Tags: apex, trigger, apextestrunresult

I have this apex test class, the only problem with this is delete isn't being covered when running test. Is there something missing from this?

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public class ProductRequiredTriggerTest {
    
    static testMethod void productRequiredTestTrigger() {
        
       WorkType workTypeRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createWorkType(true);
        //Scheduling policy creation
        FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c policy = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createSchedulingPolicy(true);
        //Creation of Operating Hour
        OperatingHours operatingHourRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createOperatingHours(true);
        //Creation of Service Territory
        ServiceTerritory territoryRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createServiceTerritory(true, 'Launceston', 'Footscray', '7250', 'Australia', operatingHourRecord.Id);
        //Work Order Creation
        WorkOrder testWorkOrderRecord = LTNG_TestDataFactory.createWorkOrders(1, true, workTypeRecord.Id, territoryRecord.Id)[0];
        
        DateTime earliestStartTime = DateTime.now();
        DateTime dueDateTime = earliestStartTime.addDays(7);
        
        ServiceAppointment newSA = new ServiceAppointment();
        newSA.ParentRecordId = testWorkOrderRecord.id;
        newSA.Status = 'None';
        newSA.EarliestStartTime = earliestStartTime;
        newSA.DueDate = dueDateTime;
        newSA.Net_Payable_Amount__c = 1020;
        
        insert newSA;
        
        Product2 product = new Product2();
        product.Name = 'Product X';
        product.Duration__c = 30;    
        product.ProductCode = 'productX';
        product.LTNG_ProductType__c = 'Equipment';
        insert product;
        
        Product2 product1 = new Product2();
        product1.Name = 'Product Y';
        product1.Duration__c = 30;    
        product1.ProductCode = 'productY';
        product1.LTNG_ProductType__c = 'Equipment';
        insert product1;
        
        ProductRequired newProductRequired = new ProductRequired();
        newProductRequired.LTNG_ServiceAppointment__c = newSA.id;
        newProductRequired.Product2Id = product.id;
        newProductRequired.QuantityRequired = 1;
        newProductRequired.ParentRecordId = testWorkOrderRecord.id;
        //newProductRequired.LTNG_UnitPrice__c = 1020;
        insert newProductRequired;
        
        Pricebook2 customPricebook = new Pricebook2(
            Name = 'Price Book',
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert customPricebook;
        
        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 1020,
            IsActive = true
        );
        Insert pbe1;
        
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 1020,
            IsActive = true
        );
        Insert pbe;
        
        newProductRequired.Product2Id = product1.Id;
        update newProductRequired;
        
        newProductRequired.QuantityRequired = 2;
        update newProductRequired;     
        
        delete newProductRequired; 
        //System.assertEquals(newProductRequired.IsDeleted, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use [edit] and include the class / trigger under test

Comment: did something similar. thanks

Comment: ??  I only see the test class, not the code-under-test (which would be the trigger/trigger helpers that process the delete